# Black Holes 2D or 3D?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, event-horizon, singularities

Are [black holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) 2 dimensional or 3 Dimensional. If they were 3 Dimensional it would make more sense that wherever you approach it the gravity would be the same. But images on the internet show it as a 2 dimensional body.

Comment: Neither I think at least 4D

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72824/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Black holes are 3 dimensional. They are simply celestial bodies like planets or stars but have so much mass that even light cannot escape their gravity if it is within a certain distance from them.

Images on the internet probably show a black hole's potential energy curve (even if they mistakenly label it as just a black hole). You also need to consider that sometimes artists will draw things that aren't completely accurate but are meant to be visually striking. Don't let that confuse you, black holes are 3D

Comment: Not to mention that every image on the internet is 2D, with some displays able to give only an illusion of 3D

Answer (score 1):

In our universe of 3 spatial dimensions the event horizon is a 2-sphere.

Ignoring time, $t$, the universe is a $3$ dimensional manifold because it takes $3$ 'numbers' to specify a point within it. An event horison is a $2$ dimensional manifold because it takes $2$ numbers to set a point within it.

Answer (score 1):

As per current observations spacetime is made up of 1 temporal dimension plus 3 spatial dimensions, therefore each physical object is spatially 3-dimensional. However a black hole does not have a finite extension as it is conceived, at least classically, as a singularity in space showing spherical symmetry in case of Schwarzschild (static) or axially symmetry in case of Kerr (rotating) solution to the EFE (Einstein field equations) in vacuum.
Graphical representations of a black hole may picture a 3d image of the event horizon and ergosurface or a 2d section of them.