# Theory on the anatomy of a black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, singularities, hawking-radiation

I'm pretty new to physics, and have just started really getting into it the last year or so, but I had an idea about the anatomy of a black hole.

- I was wondering if it were possible that a black hole could be made of compressed matter, in a spherical shape, instead of a "hole."
- Or if it were possible that the extreme gravity could somehow cause a fusion-type reaction that could turn physical matter into pure energy, which may explain the "halo" that seems to refract around the outer edges, while still pulling in light. And If this whole theory may be able to explain how particles, or radiation can also be ejected from the event horizon.

Like I said, I'm new to physics, and am still learning, and would love to make a career out of it someday, but I felt I should try and get involved more.

Comment: gravity pulls everything into spheres on a large enough scale. why did you think it was a hole?

Comment: See [Shape of a black hole](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72824/25301) for point 1.

Comment: I don't know why I thought that. Probably because of all of the ideas there are on black holes, and the theories that they have. But it never really made sense that they would be anything but accumulating mass, and that everything it pulled in would still have to be there.

Comment: -1 No research effort. There are many questions on this site, and articles on the internet, which you could read to find out more about black holes.

Answer (score 1):

In classical general relativity anything inside the event horizon, whether it's matter, light, or whatever, necessarily moves inwards towards the singularity. There is no way for anything to even remain at a constant distance from the singularity, let alone move away from it. This means there cannot be any structures inside the event horizon - the only thing present is the singularity.

We expect quantum gravity effects to change this conclusion, but we have no theory of quantum gravity and there are no widely accepted ideas about what the quantum effects do.

Comment: What about when the black holes absorbs matter, and the event horizon expands? Does that mean that the singularity itself is growing?

Comment: @JefferyMercer: GR cannot describe what happens at the singularity. It predicts that anything crossing the horizon reaches the singularity in finite (short!) time as measured by the falling object. But what happens at the singularity GR cannot say. In any case most of us believe that singularities don't exist because some quantum gravity effect will smear them out.

Comment: Do you know where could I learn more about quantum gravity and its effects? I'm a really slow learner when it comes to a lot of reading and trying to retaining knowledge. But couldn't the growth of a singularity somehow change its properties, and the calculations needed to make a hypothesis about it?