# Are black holes disc shaped, or sphere?

Tags: black-holes, event-horizon

Been wondering, are black holes disc shaped pulling in only one/two directions, or spheres pulling in all directions?

Comment: Spheres pulling in all directions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the shape of a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/72824/)